Can every square matrix be written as the product of two smaller matrices?
Can every square matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be written as the product $XY$ of two smaller matrices $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times k}, Y \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times n}$, for every $k \geq 1$?
If not, can it

Be approximated with any guarantees on the error as the product of two such smaller matrices
Same as (1), with some additional constraint on $k$?

I initially thought that the answer to my first question was trivially "no", since $X$ and $Y$ may have far less numbers in total than $A$ has, suggesting that there's more "possibilities" for $A$ than there are for $(X, Y)$. However, since there's a bijection from $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$, and thus also from $\mathbb{R}^{2nk} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n^2}$, the cardinality of all possible $A$ should (if I'm not mistaken) be equal to that of all possible $(X, Y)$.

consider the 2x2 identity matrix, can you write it as the outer product of two vectors?

No.\ If $k\lt n$, then a matrix $Y\in\mathbb{R}^{k\times n}$ must have non-trivial nullspace (since it corresponds to a linear map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^k$); so $XY$ will necessarily have non-trivial nullspace, and thus cannot equal an invertible matrix $A$. And more generally, it cannot equal any matrix $A$ with nullity strictly smaller than $n-k$.

There's the constraint $\operatorname{rk}(XY)\le \min{k,n}$. It is however true that for all $A\in\Bbb F^{n\times n}$ and for all $k\ge \operatorname{rk}A$ there are $X\in\Bbb F^{n\times k}$ and $Y\in\Bbb F^{k\times n}$ such that $A=XY$.

@ArturoMagidin Why are you putting what amounts to basically a full answer in the comment section?

@Arthur Because it is not "a full answer"; it does not address points either 1 nor 2, nor does it address whether you can in other situations. Any particular reason you failed to notice that in your haste to complain about it?

@ArturoMagidin You're right. I missed that. And yet it doesn't matter in the slightest for my complaint. The comment box itself tells you what it is and isn't for, and I maintain that your comment is exactly what it tells you not to do. Partial though it may be.

@Arthur I do not like posting partial answers to questions quickly, because it tends to reduce engagement by others. If you don't like it... well, you don't do it, so you are  done with what you can do about it. Other than post comments that show you aren't reading things carefully enough to be complaining, that is.

This is possible iff $\text{rank}(A) \le k$; this is a good exercise.
The question of best approximation of a matrix $A$ by a matrix of rank $\le k$ is known as the low-rank approximation problem. If "best" is measured according to operator norm then the question is answered by the Eckhart-Young theorem; the best such approximation is obtained from the singular value decomposition of $A$ by keeping the $k$ largest singular values and deleting the rest, and the error of this approximation in the operator norm is the $k+1$-th singular value $\sigma_{k+1}$.
Cardinalities are irrelevant; the important constraint here is that an $n \times k$ matrix has rank at most $\text{min}(n, k)$, and that $\text{rank}(XY) \le \text{min}(\text{rank}(X), \text{rank}(Y))$. More intuitively, applying linear maps cannot increase the dimension of a vector space, so $Y$ "squeezes" $\mathbb{R}^n$ into some subspace of $\mathbb{R}^k$ and $X$ cannot "expand" this subspace out into a higher-dimensional vector space. This idea remains correct even if we replace $X$ and $Y$ by smooth maps, by Sard's lemma.

Thank you very much for the quick answer!
Is there some sort of possible bound on the (k+1)th singular value of a matrix (or some heuristics for its order of magnitude for most matrices) -- preferably one that I can understand without knowing a whole lot about singular values?

@Bob: if $A$ is self-adjoint, or more generally normal, then its singular values are the absolute values of its eigenvalues. In general the singular values are the square roots of the eigenvalues of $A^{\dagger} A$. Without any further information there's no bound better than $\sigma_k(A) \le | A |$, the operator norm of $A$ (which is $\sigma_1(A)$); this bound is tight for scalar multiples of the identity, for example. Of course in this context this bound isn't very informative because it just tells you the best rank $k$ approximation is at least as good as... the zero matrix.

For each square matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ there is a unique natural number called rank of $A$. The rank of $A$ is always less than or equal than $n$. $A$ can be written as a product of two matrices $XY$ where $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times k}$ and $Y \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times n}$ for $k$ greater or equal to its rank. It cannot be written as a product like that with $k$ less than the rank of $A$. You can see the definition of rank in your linear algebra textbook or on wikipedia or at any resource about linear algebra.
Suppose $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is an arbitrary matrix of rank $r$ and you want to approximate it as a product $XY$ where $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times k}$ and $Y \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times n}$ where $k < r$. The SVD decomposition of $A$, with all singular values except for the first $k$ thrown away, gives such an approximation. In fact, in terms of both the frobenius matrix norm and the $\ell_2$ matrix norm, there does not exist a better approximation. There exists a numerical widely used algorithm for calculating SVD. How good is such an approximation (called truncated SVD)? Well, we have that $\| A - XY \|_2^2 = \sigma_{k+1}^2$, where $XY$ is an approximation given by truncated SVD of rank $k < n$ and $\sigma_{k+1}$ denotes the $(k+1)$-th singular value of $A$. I don't know if such a bound exists for the Frobenius norm.
Your thoughts about bijections between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ don't work for this because those bijections are not continuous. They are not nice functions. To represent big lists of numbers with small lists of numbers using some kind of bijection, you would at the very least need the bijection to be continuous.
